# NSOutlineView drag-n-drop multiple items to single xml file Finder

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drag-and-drop, nsoutlineview

I have a `NSOutlineView` with drag and drop support to reorder rows. Now I would like to add an export of the selected rows to a opml file in Finder. I've managed to set up `NSFilePromiseProvider` during `outlineView:pasteboardWriterForItem:`, which is called for every single row.

My current testing environment includes dummy methods of all related drag-n-drop delegate methods:
`NSDraggingSource`, `NSFilePromiseProviderDelegate`, `NSPasteboardItemDataProvider`, `NSPasteboardTypeOwner`, `NSPasteboardWriting`, and the source and destination delegate methods of `NSOutlineViewDataSource`.
With a minimal method body and a print out whenever they are called.
And most of the time delegate methods are only called for specific `NSPasteboardType` like `NSPasteboardTypeString`.

How can I have one promised file for all selected rows at once? In the end I want to drag e.g., 3 rows from my outline view to the Desktop with 1 file created 'export.opml'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a composition that works. Turns out `outlineView:pasteboardWriterForItem:` is not the right place to instantiate the `NSFilePromiseProvider`. Here is what worked for me:

```
ThisClass <NSFilePromiseProviderDelegate>
...

- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView writeItems:(NSArray *)items toPasteboard:(NSPasteboard *)pasteboard {
    NSFilePromiseProvider *prov = [[NSFilePromiseProvider alloc] initWithFileType:@"public.xml" delegate:self];
    [pasteboard writeObjects:@[prov]];
    return YES;
}

- (nonnull NSString *)filePromiseProvider:(nonnull NSFilePromiseProvider *)filePromiseProvider fileNameForType:(nonnull NSString *)fileType {
    return @"myfile.opml";
}

- (void)filePromiseProvider:(nonnull NSFilePromiseProvider *)filePromiseProvider writePromiseToURL:(nonnull NSURL *)url completionHandler:(nonnull void (^)(NSError * _Nullable))completionHandler {
    NSLog(@"%@ %@", url, filePromiseProvider.userInfo);
    // write to file ...
    completionHandler(nil);
}
```